# PhoneGap check Internet connection on device vs mobile browser

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to Phonegap and JqueryMobile. I need to check the internet connection on device. After seeing some solution on net I got confused about approaches. some solutions is suggesting to use PG API like network manager and connection while some using JQMobile method to check connection.

My question is which to prefer ? or what are the target areas for both the implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap have own function to check Internet connection available or not.[Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html) is that official document.

- Check Internet is [Online](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online)  `document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);`
- Check Internet is [Offline](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline) `document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);`

You need to set

`<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />` permission in `config.xml` for android.

You have to add some permission in manifest as below,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/d5XYR/

In this case timer will check internet connection every 100 ms and set final result into a javascript global variable.

Everything depends on this line:

```
window.navigator.onLine -- it will be false if the user is offline.
```

Final solution:

```
var connectionStatus = false;

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        connectionStatus = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    }, 100);
    $(document).on('click', '#check-connection', function () {
        alert(connectionStatus);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you are using JqueryMobile to develop application then use this method. Above code tested on browsers and iPads.

Comment: I kept this question after seeing above solution on stack. but I did see PG and JQM both having their own way but under the hood I guess HTML5 specs is working. But, still I am not clear should I make use of JQM API or instead call PG API.