# Unable to open photo library in Android using cordova phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am building a Andriod mobile app using HTML5,CSS3,Javascript, Phonegap

I am unable to open Photo Album or Library on my Android device. I get the error saying Cannot read property PictureSourceType |  PHOTOLIBRARY | SAVEDPHOTOALBUM in eclipse logcat? Please help ?

logcat

```
06-30 01:02:37.268: D/CordovaLog(1156): file:///android_asset/www/profile_uploadonly.html: Line 24 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PictureSourceType' of undefined
06-30 01:02:37.268: E/Web Console(1156): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PictureSourceType' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/profile_uploadonly.html:24
06-30 01:02:56.618: D/CordovaLog(1156): file:///android_asset/www/profile_uploadonly.html: Line 90 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PHOTOLIBRARY' of undefined
06-30 01:02:56.618: E/Web Console(1156): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PHOTOLIBRARY' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/profile_uploadonly.html:90
06-30 01:03:02.719: D/CordovaLog(1156): file:///android_asset/www/profile_uploadonly.html: Line 91 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SAVEDPHOTOALBUM' of undefined
06-30 01:03:02.719: E/Web Console(1156): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SAVEDPHOTOALBUM' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/profile_uploadonly.html:91
```

. profile_uploadonly.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="File.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="FileTransfer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="FileTransferError.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script>

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    alert("inside large image")

    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}


</script>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>

<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068516/phonegap-3-apache-cordova-error-with-getpicture-cannot-read-property-picture

Comment: @Thanks Aravin it worked